# Can I have a Rails route with no path separator between controller and :id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I currently have a URL that looks like this for a particular resource:

http://test.litmus.local/tests/186/versions/8/screenshots

I want it to look like this:

http://test.litmus.local/tests/186/v8/screenshots

Is there a way to change versions/:version_id to v:version_id?

Here's what my routes for those resources currently look like:

```
  map.resources :tests do |test|
    test.resources :versions, :path_prefix => '/tests/:test_id' do |version|
      version.section '/:section', :controller => "versions", :action => 'show', :requirements => { :section => /...blah.../ }
    end
  end
```

I've omitted anything irrelevant, so apologies if I've broken anything.

I'm using Rails 2.3.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd:

- make the `v8` be interpreted as `:version_id`
- add a constraint to the param, basically matching the following regexp: `\Av(\d*)\z`
- extract the id using the regexp inside the controller

Comment: I did this, then overrode version#to_param. I also had to gsub away the 'v' in the controller's before_filter. Seems to be working perfectly, thanks!